# How to check is_home() from wp plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wp plugin. So I want

```
if(!is_home()){
  load js & css
}
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> [is_front_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

(this will work if you have selected manual home page from > `settings >reading >front page`, always do check Wordpress codex for information based on it's built in functions. try with the below function if it works for you.

```
if(is_front_page()){
 // display content for homepage 
} else {
 // display content for others.
}
```

you can use

> [is_home()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home)

the above will work normally for the default wordpress hompage that contains latest 10 posts / normal blog posts.

```
if(is_home()){
 // content for homepage (normal)
} else {
 // content for other pages
}
```